# How to search a record from database by date range in c#

Tags: c#

I have one column called date in database and my database datecolumn contain like this 2013-02-22,but in front end iam using 2 ajaxdate pickers and searching for a record
 i am writing the query like this,i want to know whether it is correct or not.

```
SELECT * from table where Date between '" + txtfromdate.Text +"' and '"+txttodate +"'";
```

Comment: Hello [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), my old friend, I've come to talk with you again...

Comment: Yes, you use the `BETWEEN` operator. Did you try it ? Did it work? Are the results that you get from executing from this query correct when you check manually?

Comment: As @ChrisSinclair said to avoid SQL Injection is better to Create a stored procedure and pass in as parameters the from and to date range.

Comment: Obligatory and apparently never overused reference: http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 2):

You query is correct (assuming you pass properly formatted date values), but not acceptable for anything but one time programming exercise.

Please use parametrized SQL query to avoid SQL injection. Starting point is [SqlCommand.Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) .

This is approximate code you need to use parameters:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
  "SELECT * FROM table WHERE Date BETWEEN @date1 AND @date2", connection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date1", DateTime.Parse(txtfromdate.Text));
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date1", DateTime.Parse(txttodate));
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```